# How can I trigger a route handler manually in express js?

Tags: node.js, express, run-middleware

suppose I have a simple express js application like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.json({ hello: 'world' });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I want to be able to go to the command line, require the app, start the server and simulate a request. Something like this:

```
var app = require('./app');
app.listen(3000);
app.dispatch('/') // => {hello:"world"}
```

Comment: You could make a request using the `http` module.

Comment: I would prefer to know how does express handles this internally, I've been searching through the source code but I honestly couldn't find it.

Comment: Express doesn't really have something like this, since you'd have to mock out everything about the request and the response.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `run-middleware` module exactly for that. This is working by creating new Request & Response objects, and call your app using those objects.

```
app.runMiddleware('/yourNewRoutePath',{query:{param1:'value'}},function(responseCode,body,headers){
     // Your code here
})
```

More info:

- Module page in [Github](https://github.com/AminaG/node-run-middleware) & [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-middleware);
- [Examples of use run-middleware module](https://github.com/AminaG/node-run-middleware/blob/master/example.js)

Disclosure: I am the maintainer & first developer of this module.

Answer (score 3):

this solution works perfectly by using express 4.16 
(and optionally -[express promise router](https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router) , which is great wrapper for error handling)

its straightforward, without using router inside a router nor re-write the request, like in the other suggested answers

just change the URL in the request and return it to router handle function

```html
const router = require('express-promise-router')();

router.post('/signin', function(req, res , next) {

    if (req.body.Username === 'admin') {
        req.url = '/admin/signin'   
        router.handle(req, res, next)
    }
    else  {  // default doctor
        req.url = '/doctors/signin'
        router.handle(req, res, next)
    }

});

router.post('/doctors/signin',someCallback1)
router.post('/admin/signin',someCallback1)
```

Answer (score 3):

These two options worked for me without any error:

## option 1

```
app.post('/one/route', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = '/another/route'
  req.method = 'GET'
  next();
});

app.get('/another/route', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hi, I am another route");
});
```

## option 2

```
app.post('/one/route', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = '/another/route'
  req.method = 'GET'
  app._router.handle(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/another/route', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hi, I am another route");
});
```

- Express : 4.15.4
- No extra library or npm module is required

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, there isn't a way to switch to a specific route internally, but there is a way to flag the request, then move on to the next route:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if("nextRouteCondition"){
        req.skip = true;
        return next();
    }
})
```

This may allow you to accomplish what you want to do.